# Glassfish - uploading images - doing it right

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish-3, multipartform-data, servlet-3.0

I am on latest glassfish (3.1.2) - so no need for apache FileItem and no bugs with getPart(). I read that the best practice on uploading images is saving them on the file system (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348363/what-is-the-best-practice-for-storing-uploaded-images) for instance). I am editing already existing code - smelly at that - so I had the idea to do :

```
Part p1 = request.getPart("file");
System.out.println("!!!!!P1 : " + p1);
```

Prints :

```
!!!!!P1 : File name=DSC03660.JPG, 
StoreLocation=C:\_\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\elkethe\upload_7cb06306_138b413999a__7ffa_00000000.tmp, 
size=2589152bytes, isFormField=false, FieldName=file
```

newlines mine. In the code people are doing :

```
if (request.getParameter("crop") != null) {
    // get path on the server
    String outputpath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath(
            "images/temp/" + session.getId() + ".jpg");
    // store photo
    InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
    createPhoto(is, outputpath);
    session.setAttribute("photo_path", "images/temp/" + session.getId()
            + ".jpg");
    response.sendRedirect("cropping");
    return;
}
```

Where

```
private void createPhoto(InputStream is, String outputpath) {
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(outputpath);
        // write bytes taken from uploaded file to target file
        int ch = is.read();
        while (ch != -1) {
            os.write(ch);
            ch = is.read();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Helpers.close(os);
    }
}
```

Now what happens is that the file is uploaded in the StoreLocation (???) on submitting the form so apparently all this  `p1.getInputStream()` is for naught.

My questions are :

- what is StoreLocation ? How tmp are those glassfish uploads ? Where are all those parameters set ? I did read BalusC' [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/281545) - but there is no mention of StoreLocation (google is not very helpful [either](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=StoreLocation%20glassfish)).
- What would be a more professional way of handling the situation - including keeping the photos outside the webroot - but using facilities glassfish provides (if it does provide) ?
- Even p1 printing so nice escapes me (it does not [seem](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) to Override `toString()`)

Interested in tips even in how should one rename the photos etc (is this sessionID thing Right ? - check also the time trick) :

```
if (request.getParameter("save") != null) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String path = "images/upload/" + session.getId() + time + ".jpg";
    String outputpath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath(path);
    // store photo
    InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
    createPhoto(is, outputpath);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of the class StoreLocation? Doesn't look familiar to me

Comment: @gerrytan: not a class - just a printout in toString() of `Parts` - will be updating the question soon - I think I can answer some of it - I am just too busy at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is StoreLocation ? How tmp are those glassfish uploads ? Where are all those parameters set ?

[StoreLocation](https://github.com/ancoron/glassfish-main/blob/4013c456bd27c339c8d48784571d17289901da3a/appserver/web/web-core/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/fileupload/PartItem.java#L605) is just the the java.io.File object for the `FileItem`'s
 data's temporary location on the disk. Resides in `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` which defaults to `%GLASSFISH_HOME%\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\webApp`. Those uploads are as tmp as anything (*The lifetime of the file is tied to the lifetime of the `FileItem` instance; the file will be deleted when the instance is garbage collected* - from [here](https://github.com/ancoron/glassfish-main/blob/4013c456bd27c339c8d48784571d17289901da3a/appserver/web/web-core/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/fileupload/PartItem.java#L639)). Haven't yet managed to change the value of `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` programmatically (comment please) - it is the `tempdir` property of the [sun-web-app element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beayb/index.html) of the sun-web.xml.

> What would be a more professional way of handling the situation - including keeping the photos outside the webroot - but using facilities glassfish provides (if it does provide) ?

Well a more professional way is to Use `Part.write()` to *move* the file to the desired location. Due to glassfish implementation though you can't supply an absolute path to write - a chore. I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738244/glassfish-part-write-no-absolute-paths-workaround).

As to where to save the file : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664715/281545

That is for saving the file - to serve it from a location outside the app you need to define "alternatedocroot" properties in the sun-web.xml (or glassfish-web.xml).

> Even p1 printing so nice escapes me (it does not seem to Override toString())

Oh yes [it does](https://github.com/ancoron/glassfish-main/blob/4013c456bd27c339c8d48784571d17289901da3a/appserver/web/web-core/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/fileupload/PartItem.java#L694)

> Interested in tips even in how should one rename the photos etc (is this sessionID thing Right ? - check also the time trick)

No it is not - I tend towards `File#createTempFile()` - anyway this is a different question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741780/servlets-choose-a-filename-for-uploaded-files)

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to pick a path on the filesystem where photos will be uploaded. Often this path is programmed to be configurable via java system property (eg: by passing `-Dcom.mycompany.uploadPath=/path/to/photos/dir` system property on JVM arguments).

You can also use java system propeties to find environment specific path: `user.dir`, `user.home` etc. See [System Properties on Java SE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). Or to use glassfish-relative path, see [glassfish system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4507/abhey/index.html).

Once you have reference to [Part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html), it's just about doing file IO to copy the uploaded file into this upload path, eg:

```
Part part = // obtain part somehow..
String photoFileName = // build a file name somehow..
InputStream photoInputStream = part.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream photoOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("com.mycompany.uploadPath") + File.separator + photoFileName);
IOUtils.copy(photoInputStream, photoOutputStream);
// close streams here...
```

Code above uses [apache IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) for convenience but feel free to write your own copy method. You should also add exception handling method

Comment: have a look at my answer - my main concern was to move (as opposed to _copy_) the file - and to figure out what all those glassfish cruft was