# Displaying images stored in a database using PHP

Tags: php

For my current assignment I'm trying to store files into the DB and display them. Currently I have no problem storing the files but I can't display them properly. I'm using this in my main form.

```
<td><a href=getImage.php?id='.$file[0].'"  />Resume</a></td>
```

And this is the query I'm using to get the file out of the DB.

```
  $sql = "SELECT file FROM table WHERE Res_ID=$referenced_ID";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
     echo "<img src=\"{$row['file']}\" /><br />";
```

The result is

> …³V!µÔ¢ošweöÿZ–îÌèEÈÎpEJ·˜kä€òþòâ­Gas
>   È*G¨¥vA¤uEN¤S]‰:ñY“iwØ8‡¥e]ØÝGÑ‘øQÍ!«3¨ÄvÙÁu§]zÕÿOã^ssÌuáY7WP“ÔT6Æà™ëâþÊQË!üi­oe8
>   9ô5ã?ÛSÇÔ‘RÃâ›˜VCBh¹>Ï³=BïÃVwåçÔW#¯|8†ufŠ4ob1PiÞ=q(,>µÐYx®Æ÷¥ò›Ñ5b½äy6«ðÆbÍ²Ï¡®fóá–
>   í„Î¾‹’xvîYVEöæ«6§]|²½ýj‡Ï#åËßjv™-k.u\ŠÈ›O–#ó!ÐŠúÊmcLþ-¹ïšÆÔ4ïkùñE¸ÿ0h±j§‘òù
>   Ôˆì¼¯íº×ÂÝã/g:»¸âïþ=³-²û?áHÑI3ŒKÙW¨ÍNºŽî-Â¶_Ã@IÙ¸{Tiû¸>â€3ÿu7@V[àü­š‘í•ùT[9\Ó’ª?oçJ©ù…69Ùxß÷¹©ö¼
>   |ÊOµ°™W#@êàÔ²iw®»–uõ5Eíåˆà«ôÅHä¯"‘\PˆÙŽ>ïÖœÖò'¡÷†^Ž@3Sg+ÀéYžt±uBG­>=H'ÞB>”À¾7ƒè)É#)åsU×S‰‡R>µ"\£ô4‹é"ç=D/ÿ-
>   š¦¼ô©àuCó'´‰ Ë7çPëÑ¿Z½åÛÌ>\Mk
>   &Ê±œÒ0ê*#)ÏAVæ€©#Bd`^):Ü²¯ü*îÛERk†^ù¦CiÃsõ¦
>   ší¹Îj¬“*øhfï¶‘¬†CqíH’ëëIæsŒŠÐ{=ÍW{
>   :dÓ¸aÐœýjXîæCÃA:æ”CŽÿe5iG£}h7I7ßCüê¬8èqP–t<Ò…©£¸MÄúbª¼EM'ÚJš‘oPýôÏ½Hˆ2GµZ¶¾T
>   H/Ò¢yb“§ò¦R9ÓC6,n...

I'm using images as a sample at the moment but the finished php should eventually allow to display PDF documents. If it's any help I'm using phpmyadmin and MySQLi.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348363/what-is-the-best-practice-for-storing-uploaded-images and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: if you content type is image/jpg you shouldn't output html like `<img src=\"`

Comment: Try it without the HTML markup in the getImage.php

Comment: Looks like you  are trying to output inline image src. If that is the case please note, that the src attribute of img tag should tell the browser, that it contains the image itself, like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML). This might help too [base64_encode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, storing the file location in the database is much better than storing the file's data in the database. BUT if you need to store the file contents in the database for some reason, there are two methods. One is using the HTML data: URL and the other is having a PHP file as the middle man.

For the PHP Middle Man method, look at the answer above mine where it sets the header information and then echo's the file contents. The file extension doesn't matter since browsers refer to the content-type header instead of file extensions.

For the Data URL method, which can be placed directly in your code easily check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

```
<?php
    // Array of valid Mime Types, prevents possible XSS methods.
    $valid_mimes = array(
        'image/png',
        'image/gif',
        'image/jpeg'
    );

    // Obtain Mime Type using finfo
    // Finfo allows for strings instead of file path
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($row['file']);

    // Check if mime is in our $valid_mimes array
    if(!in_array($mime,$valid_mimes)) {
        // Handle Error
        echo 'Illegal Mime Type: '.$mime;
        die();
    }

    $b64 = base64_encode($row['file']);
    echo '<img src="data:'.$mime.';base64,'.$b64.'" />';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this into a real answer I was too lazy.

Answer (score 0):

You cant output `<img src=\` as an output it will corrupt the image file and
Please use `getImage.php` as a different file to output images or verify that no output is printed before,after or in mid of image else it will corrupt the image.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$sql = "SELECT file FROM table WHERE Res_ID=$referenced_ID";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $row['file'];
}
```