# Conversion from file to bitmap in android

Tags: php, android, file, bitmap, server

Ok I have updated my question. This is my upload image to server project. Everything works fine no errors, but I keep getting files that are 10, 12 or 16 bytes. But with right name and type.

```
            public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
String attachmentName = "bitmap";
File f;
private ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Bitmap bit;
ByteArrayBody bitmapBody;
ContentBody contentPart;
private Uri filePath;
private String stringPath;
byte[] bitmapdata;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (SDK_INT > 8) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}




 private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        Log.d(""+filePath,"PATHHH");
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void getStringImage(){
    try {

    stringPath = getRealPathFromUri(getApplicationContext(), filePath);
     f = new File(stringPath);
     Log.d("FAJLEE" + f, "2");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100 /*ignored for png*/ , bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }
    }





public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }



 public void uploadImage(){
 try {
     Log.d("Stefna ", "ajdbarovde");
     DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     InputStream responseStream = null;
     String responseString = "";
     try {
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://studentskioglas.com/aplikacija/upload.php");

           BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
             //   bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length, bmOptions);
             Log.d("Usao u fajlee","");

         HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                 .addBinaryBody("bitmap", bitmapdata, ContentType.create("image/jpg"), f.getName())
                 .build();
         Log.d("Stefan ", f+"FAJLEEE");

         httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

         System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);Log.d("Stefan", "ispod");
         try {
             System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
             System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             if (resEntity != null) {
                 Log.d("Response content l: " + resEntity.getContentLength(), "");

                 responseStream = resEntity.getContent();
                 if (responseStream != null) {
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
                     String responseLine = br.readLine();
                     String tempResponseString = "";
                     while (responseLine != null) {
                         tempResponseString = tempResponseString + responseLine + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                         responseLine = br.readLine();
                     }
                     br.close();
                     if (tempResponseString.length() > 0) {
                         responseString = tempResponseString;
                         Log.d(""+responseString,"");
                     }
                 }

             }

         } finally {
             response = null;
         }
     } finally {
         httpclient = null;
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } } 

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){
        getStringImage();
        uploadImage();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
    }
```

My paths look fine. First I thought that problem lays down in bitmap to file conversion but it doesn't. So I've tried to convert it back to see if there is some malfunction I've removed AsyncTask and now I can see image converted back from file so I know that I'm sending good file with proper size and every parameters. But on server I got small files that when I download can't see. This is my PHP script on server side.

```
<?php

$target_path = "images/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['bitmap']['name']); 

if(file_put_contents($target_path, $_FILES['bitmap']['name'])) {


echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['bitmap']['name']).

" has been uploaded";

} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
} ?>
```

Just to update I have found the answer. Error was in file_put_contents it should be move_uploaded_file but with $_FILE['your tag']['tmp_name']. Don't get confused to change it to $_FILE['your tag']['name'] because ['tmp_name'] is the name of your file in that particular moment and it is name that server sees.

Comment: If `uploadImage()` is `AsyncTask` then you are calling `imageView.setImageBitmap(bit)` before `bit` variable has been initialized. But it is hard to tell because code fragments you have posted do not give complete picture of what is going on.

Comment: You are very good. That was really my problem. So I'have removed Async Task and now I see image. So that is not my problem. Now I'm sure that i'm sending good image. But why my files that I read on server are so small ? They are not 0 bytes.. @Dalija Prasnikar

Comment: Check size of `bitmapdata` you are sending to server and compare that to size you are getting on the server. If there is difference then something is wrong in sending/retrieving code, if not then your `bitmapdata` contains wrong data.

Comment: Few observations, you are encoding bitmapdata as PNG, and send to server as image/jpg. Next, you are way to fond of using member variables, use functions that return result instead - `getStringImage` is perfect example. Using member fields makes it harder to track what is going on in your code. There is also too much loading and saving images from and to different files and bitmaps, I have hard time trying to understand what you want to do, besides uploading file to server.

Comment: My bitmap data is 16 like I get on server but I don't know why ? I have used this code                                                                                 Log.d("DA", "bm size: "+bitmap.getByteCount()/1024); 
Log.d("DAA", "baos size: "+bos.size() / 1024);
Log.d("DAAA", "byte size: " + bitmapdata.length / 1024);                    First one logs 987 other two logs 16 but why ? @Dalija Prasnikar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the helper methods below that works quite well. Give them a try.

```
public static Bitmap convertBLOB2Bitmap(byte[] blob) {
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length, options);
    return tmp;
}


public static byte[] convertBitmap2BLOB(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that this will help me but it doesn't. I don't know why ?    @Florian Barth

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that `onActivityResult` you don't get the right image?

Comment: Butt I do because when I put variable 'bitmap'  in imageView everything works fine. @Florian Barth

Comment: It works fine your code and mine original, problem was that I put code in AsyncTask function so my variable bit wasn't initialized. @Florian Barth

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
File imgFile = new  File(selectedImageUrl);
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Thank's but it doesn't work. He goes either way in ' if ' but doesn't convert back image. @Ravneet Singh

Comment: Problem was with AsyncTask. @Ravneet Singh